# How to check if value exists in struct and save another value in array

Tags: arrays, loops, go, hashmap

I'm not exactly sure how to do this in Go, I'm just starting to work with it so I'm not familiar on how it should be done.

The idea is this: I have a `struct` created inside a function:

```
XSiteGroup := struct {
        siteURL string
        siteIDs []string
    }{}
```

I have implemented a request that gets an array of objects; this objects have the following structure:

```
{
   "siteId": "",
   "merchantName": "",
   "friendlyTitle": "",
   "url": ""
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through that array and store each `url` I find as a "key" without duplicates, and then store the `siteId` value of each object on the `siteIDs` array of the struct `XSiteGroup`. So let's say the following scenario:

```
{
   "siteId": "5050",
   "merchantName": "",
   "friendlyTitle": "",
   "url": "url1.com"
},
{
   "siteId": "4050",
   "merchantName": "",
   "friendlyTitle": "",
   "url": "url2.com"
},
{
   "siteId": "8060",
   "merchantName": "",
   "friendlyTitle": "",
   "url": "url1.com"
}
```

Having the result from above, I would need to store something like:

```
{
  siteURL: "url1.com",
  siteIDs: ["5050", "8060"]
}
```

I have something like this at the moment to loop the array of sites I have:

```
for _, site := range xwebsites {
        u, _ := url.Parse(site.URL)
        urlString := strings.ReplaceAll(u.Host, "www.", "")

        // So I'm thinking here I should handle the struct I created to store values 
        }
```

Please let me know if I'm not clear or what additional information is needed.

Comment: Are you just asking how to check if a value is in a slice?

Comment: Hmm, not exactly, I make a request to an endpoint and I receive an array of objects which have two properties: `siteId` and `url`; so I need to check if the `url` is already on my struct and if it is, I add the `siteId` value to the `siteIDs` array of the struct; I'll include this on the question to provide more info

Comment: @JimB edited the question now

Comment: You will need map to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value doesn't exist, you have to create it. You can check that with `value, ok := map[key]`.

```golang
type xsitegroup struct {
  url     string
  ids     []string
}

// A mapping between urls and their site groups.
sitegroups := make(map[string]*xsitegroup)
    
for _, website := range xwebsites {
        url := website["url"]

        sitegroup, ok := sitegroups[url]

        // A sitegroup for this URL does not exist
        if !ok {
            // Create the sitegroup
            sitegroup = &xsitegroup{ url: url, ids: []string{} }
            // Add it to the mapping
            sitegroups[url] = sitegroup
        }
     
        // Append the site id.   
        sitegroup.ids = append(sitegroup.ids, website["siteId"])
}
```

[Demonstration](https://go.dev/play/p/0zciyT8onzS)

Comment: Thank you; I'll try this out, in this case how is the syntax read? when you say `make(map[string]*xsitegroup)` how should I interpret that?

Comment: @IvanS95: you need to start with a grasp of syntax and builtin types: trying going through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) which explains all this.

Comment: I'll go through it; I was trying your example in my code, when I get to the last line, where it says `website["siteId"]` I get an error saying that the type `model.xSite` does not support indexing, just to get an idea, is this something I should look to fix on the model I created or is it on the piece of code you provided?

Comment: @IvanS95 Since you did not provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I made `xwebsites := []map[string]string{...}` for my testing, so `website` is a hashmap. It sounds like you have `[]model.xSite`, so `website` is a `model.xSite`. That means you access `website` as a struct: `website.siteId` and `website.URL` instead of `website["url"]` and `website["siteId"]`. [Here's the complete test code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/1db5e098758e63ea707748f3afa556e1).

Comment: @IvanS95 `map[string]*xsitegroup` is a hash map where the keys are `string` and the values are pointers to `xsitegroup` structs. [`make` allocates and initializes memory for the map](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new) which is really a struct that requires initialization. Reading through [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/) will help.

Comment: @Schwern thank you again, I did change it to just `website.siteId` and the error disappeared, I'm now getting the expected output; really appreciate the help; I'll read the links you provided and keep testing things out to get the hang of it