# Slice find all structs where one property has the same value

Tags: go, grouping

I want to find similar entries and want to store them under the same id

```js
options = [
      {"ABC": [opt1, opt2]}, // opt1 and opt2 have the same id
      {"DEF": [opt3]}
]
```

The input looks like this

```js
input = [opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4] // opt1.id = opt2.id == "ABC"
```

Based on

- [remove duplicates from slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76471309/819887) and
- [sort slice of struct by two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61030110/819887)

i [attempted this demo](https://go.dev/play/p/aPmsqoTxNrb)

```golang
type Priceoption struct {
    Option      string `json:"prnumber"`
    Price       string `json:"price"`
    Setting     string `json:"setting"`
    Origin string `json:"Origin"`
}

func GetPriceOptions() []Priceoption {

    opts := []Priceoption{
        {Option: "ABC", Price: "11.00", Setting: "foo", Origin: "201"},
        {Option: "DEF", Price: "27.00", Setting: "bar", Origin: "198"},
        {Option: "XYZ", Price: "41.00", Setting: "zap", Origin: "E"},
        {Option: "DEF", Price: "27.00", Setting: "bar", Origin: "198"},
        {Option: "ABC", Price: "n/a", Setting: "foo", Origin: "201"},
    }
    return opts
}
```

And this

```golang
func main() {

    opts := GetPriceOptions()

    sort.Slice(opts, func(i, j int) bool {
        if opts[i].Option != opts[j].Option {
            return opts[i].Option < opts[j].Option
        }
        return opts[i].Price < opts[j].Price
    })
    fmt.Printf("Sorted Options List: %v\n", opts)
    opts = slices.Compact(opts) // works if every property has the same value
    fmt.Printf("Compacted List: %v\n", opts)
}
```

This works for each struct that has the same value in every property (above only `{DEF 27.00 bar 198}`). But i want to find structs where one property has the same value.

Example these two

```json
opt1 = {"Option": "ABC", "Price": "11.00", "Setting": "foo", "Origin": "201"}
opt2 = {"Option": "ABC", "Price": "n/a", "Setting": "bar", "Origin": "E"}
```

I tried to adapt [check if value exists in struct and save that in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069805/819887) to my problem

but [my DEMO Code got stuck with](https://go.dev/play/p/_0IF34oevoV).

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
> dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x20
> pc=0x4577ff]
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.main()    /tmp/sandbox1376546491/prog.go:50
> +0x23f

The line that fails is the one where i want to add an Option to the map

```golang
optiongroup.Options = append(optiongroup.Options, opt)
```

Here is the `main`

```golang
func main() {

    priceoptions := GetPriceOptions()
    optiongroups := make(map[string]*OptionGroup) // map

    for _, opt := range priceoptions {
        optId := opt.Option
        optiongroup, ok := optiongroups[optId]

        if !ok {
            optiongroup := &OptionGroup{OptId: optId, Options: []Priceoption{}}
            optiongroups[optId] = optiongroup
        }

        // Append option fails
        optiongroup.Options = append(optiongroup.Options, opt)
    }
    println("optiongroups", len(optiongroups))
}
```

- Is there a simple way to find all structs in a list where one property has the same value?
- What is my mistake to put append another option a a certain map position: `map["ABC"].Add(option)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the := from the optiongroup inside the !ok condition Append should work.

```
    if !ok {
        optiongroup = &OptionGroup{OptId: optId, Options: []Priceoption{}}
        optiongroups[optId] = optiongroup
    }
```

https://go.dev/play/p/PG_GSCVZ3Oh

Comment: Thank you, this works great. How would you go about finding out which options are sent more than once?

Comment: I think the program is already doing that, check the link: [https://go.dev/play/p/gee6ODRyajh](https://go.dev/play/p/gee6ODRyajh)

I have added following code which produced the mentioned output:
```go
    for _, value := range optiongroups {
            fmt.Println(value)
     fmt.Println(len(value.Options))
    }
```

Output:
```
    &{ABC [{ABC 11.00 foo 201} {ABC n/a foo 201}]}
    2
    &{DEF [{DEF 27.00 bar 198} {DEF 27.00 bar E}]}
    2
    &{XYZ [{XYZ 41.00 zap E}]}
    1
```